# Count the number of Unions in a query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm looking for a window function way of doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT name, 't1' as Src, '1' AS unionSet
    FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT name, 't2', '2'
    FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT name, 't3', '3'
    FROM table3
) query
```

This would result in something like:

```
alanzo,   t1,   1 
alex,     t1,   1 
frank,    t2,   2 
michelle, t2,   2
steve,    t2,   2
peter,    t3,   3
arial,    t3,   3
```

I was hoping there's a window function to count the sequence of `Src`'s -- something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Src ORDER BY name)`, but that starts at 1 each time. I don't want to have to use the `unionSet` column.

Hope this makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT query.*,
       dense_rank() over(order by src) as x
FROM (
    SELECT name, 't1' as Src
    FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT name, 't2'
    FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT name, 't3'
    FROM table3
) query
```

Comment: The `dense_rank() over(order by src)` seems gets the job done without the `row_number` portion -- `select query.*, dense_rank() over(order by src)`. Very neat! Thanks!

Comment: @Shwarz thanks, yeah I overcomplicated it. Took out the excess